# function with a loop shampoo adjust

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

Question:

> Write a function print_shampoo_instructions() with parameter
> num_cycles. If num_cycles is less than 1, print "Too few.". If more
> than 4, print "Too many.". Else, print "N : Lather and rinse."
> num_cycles times, where N is the cycle number, followed by "Done.".

Sample output with input: `2`

```
1 : Lather and rinse.
2 : Lather and rinse.
Done.
```

My Error:
Program end never reached.
This is commonly due to an infinite loop or infinite recursion.

My code is as follows:

```
def shampoo_instructions(num_cycles):
    if num_cycles < 1:
        print ('Too few.')
    elif num_cycles > 4:
        print ('Too many.')
    else:
        i = 0
    while i<num_cycles:
        print (i+1,": Lather and rinse")
    i = i + 1

    print('Done')

shampoo_instructions(2) 
user_cycles = int(input()) #cannot be altered per the program
print_shampoo_instructions(user_cycles) #cannot be altered per the program
```

Answer (score 2):

Your actually reassigning `i` *outside* of the while loop. Inside the loop you're simply printing out `i + 1`. Instead reassign the counter inside the loop:

```
while i<num_cycles:
    print (i+1,": Lather and rinse")
    i = i + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def shampoo_instructions(user_cycles):
    if user_cycles < 1:
        print("Too few.")
    elif user_cycles > 4:
        print("Too many.")
    else:
        for i in range(1, user_cycles + 1):
            print(i,":","Lather and rinse.")
        print("Done.")


user_cycles = int(input())
shampoo_instructions(user_cycles)
```

Answer (score 0):

I passed my zybooks tests with this code:

```
def print_shampoo_instructions(num_cycles):
    if num_cycles < 1:
        print("Too few.")
    elif num_cycles > 4:
        print("Too many.")   
    else:
        for i in range(1, user_cycles + 1):
            print(f"{i}: Lather and rinse.")
        print("Done.")
    

user_cycles = int(input())
print_shampoo_instructions(user_cycles)
```